# ValueError: Cannot convert <.....><....> to Excel

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, openpyxl, valueerror

hi im new to python programming. im try to web scraping a news website using python. I got the title and its links. But when i try to save it in excel file it shows value error

Here is Source code and Error

```
import requests, openpyxl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

excel = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = excel.active
sheet.title = 'Maalaimalar Links'
sheet.append(['Title','Link'])

req = requests.get("https://www.maalaimalar.com/news/topnews/1")

head_lines = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

hliness = head_lines.find_all('div', class_ = 'col-md-4 article')

for hlines in hliness:
    h2lines = hlines.find('h3').text
    link = hlines.find('a')
    print(h2lines)
    print(link.get('href'))
    sheet.append([h2lines, link])


excel.save('maalaimalar.xlsx')
```

This is the error when i execute with this line

```
sheet.append([h2lines, link])


ValueError: Cannot convert <a href="https://www.maalaimalar.com/news/topnews/2022/03/06182721/3549285/IPL-2022-Schedule-match-details-for-Chennai-super.vpf"><h3>ஐபிஎல்  2022 அட்டவணை- சென்னை அணி மோதும் ஆட்டங்கள் விவரம்</h3></a> to Excel.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to push the `BeautifulSoup` object to your excel instead extracting the `href` as in `print(link.get('href'))`:

```
link = hlines.find('a').get('href')
```

or

```
link = hlines.a.get('href')
```

#### Example

```
import requests, openpyxl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

excel = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = excel.active
sheet.title = 'Maalaimalar Links'
sheet.append(['Title','Link'])

req = requests.get("https://www.maalaimalar.com/news/topnews/1")

head_lines = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

hliness = head_lines.find_all('div', class_ = 'col-md-4 article')

for hlines in hliness:
    h2lines = hlines.find('h3').text
    link = hlines.find('a').get('href')
    sheet.append([h2lines, link])

excel.save('maalaimalar.xlsx')
```